# Parallel cluster runs almost serially

Tags: r, doparallel

I'm running a process on a local cluster inside a for-loop, like in this pseudocode:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  cl = makeCluster(32)
  runABigJobOnACluster(cl)
  stopCluster(cl)
}
```

I have to re-initialize the cluster because R is not doing a great job cleaning up the memory.  I run into an issue where, initially, the reallyBigJob runs on 32 cores, but after 1-2 loop iterations it *schedules* the jobs - I can see them in top sorted by memory usage - but only one or two of the jobs actually run.  Has anyone seen this weird behavior?